# Is there a function in R that allows you to create a new row with information in a column?

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
       Color   Food   Color   Food   Color   Food
row 1  Red     Taco   Green   Sushi  Purple  Pizza
row 2  Green   Pizza  Yellow  Salad  Red     Taco
```

I would like it to look like this

```
      Color  Food
row 1 Red    Taco 
row 2 Green  Sushi
row 3 Purple Pizza
row 4 Green  Pizza 
row 5 Yellow Salad
row 6 Red    Taco
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Duplicate column names are not recommended in `data.frame`.  Try `sapply(split.default(df1, names(df1)), unlist)` or `library(tidyverse); df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% mutate(rn = str_c('row', rowid(name))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% column_to_rownames('rn')`

Comment: The column names are duplicated because the data was exported from a survey. I was looking for a function that will allow me to align the data under the appropriate column name

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(c(t(df)), nrow = ncol(df), byrow = TRUE)),
         c("Colour", "Food"))
#>   Colour  Food
#> 1    Red  Taco
#> 2  Green Sushi
#> 3 Purple Pizza
#> 4  Green Pizza
#> 5 Yellow Salad
#> 6    Red  Taco
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Color = c("Red", "Green"), Food = c("Taco", "Pizza"
), Color = c("Green", "Yellow"), Food = c("Sushi", "Salad"), 
    Color = c("Purple", "Red"), Food = c("Pizza", "Taco")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df
#>   Color  Food  Color  Food  Color  Food
#> 1   Red  Taco  Green Sushi Purple Pizza
#> 2 Green Pizza Yellow Salad    Red  Taco
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `split.default`

```
sapply(split.default(df1, names(df1)), unlist)
```

---

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    mutate(rn = str_c('row', rowid(name))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
    column_to_rownames('rn')
```

-output

```
#     Color  Food
#row1    Red  Taco
#row2  Green Sushi
#row3 Purple Pizza
#row4  Green Pizza
#row5 Yellow Salad
#row6    Red  Taco
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Color = c("Red", "Green"), Food = c("Taco", "Pizza"
), Color = c("Green", "Yellow"), Food = c("Sushi", "Salad"), 
    Color = c("Purple", "Red"), Food = c("Pizza", "Taco")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  cbind(
    id = 1:nrow(df),
    setNames(df, ave(names(df), names(df), FUN = function(x) paste0(x, ".", seq_along(x))))
  ),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "id",
  varying = -1
)[-(1:2)]
```

which gives

```
     Color  Food
1.1    Red  Taco
2.1  Green Pizza
1.2  Green Sushi
2.2 Yellow Salad
1.3 Purple Pizza
2.3    Red  Taco
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_longer` on the dataframe directly. Using @Allan's data :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(), names_to = '.value')

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Color  Food 
#  <chr>  <chr>
#1 Red    Taco 
#2 Green  Sushi
#3 Purple Pizza
#4 Green  Pizza
#5 Yellow Salad
#6 Red    Taco
```